# Автоматизация запуска exe с параметром

Tags: cmd, тестирование, консоль, bat, автоматизация

Я тестирую написанную программу, у которой на входе 1 файл. Тестов надо сделать много, каждый раз писать в консоли как-то грустно. Можно ли сделать батник, который будет запускать exe поочередно с каждым файлом из определенной директории?

Comment: Можно. Циклы в bat определенно есть.

Comment: Есть, но я пока не разобрался, как оно работает, поэтому и написал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
:: первый параметр батника - каталог
for /F %%f in ('dir /B/D %1') do (
  echo %1/%%f
)
```

Или ещё проще:

```
for %%f in (%1/*.*) do (
  echo %1/%%f
)
```

Comment: Не сильно помогло(

Comment: А поконкретней - что именно не работает?

Comment: Да я в принципе не понял пока логику этой штуки (я вообще ни разу не писал скрипты). Зачем /F если нужен только запуск? Зачем флаги /B и /D? И самое главное - никакой реакции на добавление start в тело.

Comment: "Зачем флаги /B и /D?" не нужно - не добавляйте, или используйте свои флаги. Или вообще обходитесь без `dir`, см. второй вариант. "никакой реакции на добавление start в тело" - а какая должна быть?

Comment: Не хотел запускаться exe с параметром из цикла. Взял вариант попроще, добавил туда start "..." ...exe %ff и все путем. Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся!